# MvcMailer view in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvcmailer

I am using [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) with my website to send html emails.
seems good, but im just wondering how i can view the created emails in a browser.

eg in some newsletters they say "view this email in a browser", so i am just wondering how I can do that with MvcMailer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to put a link in the email back to your site, and then create a controller/action that uses the same view, and builds a model the same as the one you used when creating the email.

If all the data you need is in the database, you may be able to just pass a key in the querystring (note: if the mail contains potentially sensitive information, make sure the url is tamper-proof), otherwise you might need to pass in more data to allow you to reconstruct the same view that you did when generating the email.

Comment: Special note about this though - make sure you use a different class for your `preview` controller actions, or it'll blow up.